# A polynomial problem from APMO

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

$\textbf{Problem:}$Let $a,b,c,d,e,f$ be real numbers such that the polynomial $ p(x)=x^8-4x^7+7x^6+ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f $
factorises into eight linear factors $x-x_i$, with $x_i>0$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,8$. Determine all possible values of $f$.

I noticed that if a polynomial's number of positive roots matches its degree, then its derivative also has the property that all its roots are positive reals. Using this fact I tried to differentiate $5$ times and find something about $a$, which apparently failed. Then, I tried to focus on $f$ only but I couldn't find anything useful.

All sorts of helps are appreciated. Thanks in advance

$edit:$

Someone in the comment told me to use vieta's formula.At first I thought it would become too complex.But Then I realized that Using that the solution is immediate with some applications of elementary inequalities.

So,thanks to all who helped.

Comment: Did you try to differentiate 6 times?

Comment: yeah,but that canceled all the variables.

Comment: Exactly, But that quadratic polynomial should have 2 positive roots.

Comment: And it does have

Comment: This should give you an idea where the roots of the previous derivative are and about their product which is  $-a$.

Comment: If you figured out how to apply the Vieta formula to solve the question, I would encourage writing up your own solution as an answer to the question.

Comment: @JCAA sorry cause I didn't understand what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that the roots are $x_1,\cdots,x_8$.

Then using vieta's formula we have,

$\sum_{i=0}^{8}x_i=4$ and $\sum_{i \not =j} x_ix_j=7$

Then we have $\sum x_i^2=(\sum x_i)^2-2\sum x_ix_j=2$

Since all the roots are positive we can apply quadratic mean arithmatic mean inequality to get

$1/2=\sqrt{1/8 \sum x_i^2} \ge \frac{1}{8}\sum x_i=1/2$ meaning all the roots will be same and they will all equal $1/2$.
.So, $f=\frac{1}{2^8}=\frac{1}{256}$ by vieta's formula

Answer (score 1):

For any polynomial $p_1$ with only real roots, if we take the derivative and get $p_2$, and solve for the roots (in increasing order) $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ of $p_2$ then the $n+1$ roots in increasing order, $b_1,b_2,...,b_{n+1}$ of $p_1$ follow the pattern $b_1\leq a_1\leq b_2\leq a_2\leq...\leq b_n\leq a_n\leq b_{n+1}$.  Applying this to our case, using the sixth derivative:
$$\frac{d^6p}{dx^6}=20160x^2-20160x+5040=5040(4x^2-4x+1)=5040(2x-1)(2x-1)$$
Because the sixth derivative has a double root at $x=\frac{1}{2}$, $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is a root of our original polynomial.  Factoring it out, we are left with:
$$p=(x-\frac{1}{2})(x^7-\frac{7}{2}x^6+\frac{21}{4}x^5+a'x^4+b'x^3+c'x^2+d'x+e')$$
We can then repeat the process on the polynomial $x^7-\frac{7}{2}x^6+\frac{21}{4}x^5+a'x^4+b'x^3+c'x^2+d'x+e'$, and the fifth derivative gives us the quadratic $2520x^2-2520x+630=630(2x-1)(2x-1)$, which means that we have another root of $\frac{1}{2}$.  Continuing in this vein, we can conclude that all the roots of $p$ are $\frac{1}{2}$.  The coefficient $f$ is simply the product of the roots, (and is positive because the polynomial has even degree) and is therefore $(\frac{1}{2})^8=\frac{1}{256}$